# Memory Leak using C++ Exceptions

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, exception, filehandler

I'm struggling to write a little file handle class in C++11.
I know there already is a lot in the STL to actually handle files, but for learning purposes I wanted to do this by myself.

Unfortunately I don't seem understand, what effect exceptions have on the memory leakage behavior of a C++ program because Valgrind tells me, there are 2 memory leaks in following code:

file.h

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <stdio.h>

class FileDeleter {
public:
    void operator()(FILE *p);
};

class File {
public:
    File(const std::string path);

private:
    const std::string _path;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, FileDeleter> _fp;

};

#endif // FILE_H
```

file.cpp

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

#include <stdio.h>

#include "file.h"

void FileDeleter::operator()(FILE *p)
{
if (!p)
    return;

    if (fclose(p) == EOF)
        std::cerr << "FileDeleter: Couldn't close file" << std::endl;
}

File::File(const std::string path)
    : _path(std::move(path)),
      _fp(fopen(_path.c_str(), "a+"))
{
    if (!_fp)
        throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't open file");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
    File my_file("/root/.bashrc");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I did choose to open /root/.bashrc on purpose to actually make the File ctor throw the exception. If I don't throw there, Valgrind is perfectly happy.
What am I missing here in using exceptions?
How do you implement a simple file handle "correctly" (exception safe)?

Thanks in advance!

Note: the read/write operations are still missing, since I'm already struggling with the basics.

**Edit #1:**
This is the actual Valgrind output, using --leak-check=full:

```
==7998== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7998==     in use at exit: 233 bytes in 3 blocks
==7998==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 2 frees, 817 bytes allocated
==7998== 
==7998== 38 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 3
==7998==    at 0x4C27CC2: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7998==    by 0x4EEC4F8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==7998==    by 0x4EEDC30: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==7998==    by 0x4EEE047: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==7998==    by 0x40137D: main (in ../a.out)
==7998== 
==7998== 43 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 3
==7998==    at 0x4C27CC2: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7998==    by 0x4EEC4F8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==7998==    by 0x4EEDC30: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==7998==    by 0x4EEE047: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==7998==    by 0x400EBF: File::File(std::string) (in /home/frank/3Other/Code/Laboratory/c++/c++namedpipe/a.out)
==7998==    by 0x401390: main (in ../a.out)
==7998== 
==7998== 152 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 3
==7998==    at 0x4C27730: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7998==    by 0x4E8F8F2: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==7998==    by 0x400E9B: File::File(std::string) (in /home/frank/3Other/Code/Laboratory/c++/c++namedpipe/a.out)
==7998==    by 0x401390: main (in ../a.out)
==7998== 
==7998== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7998==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7998==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7998==      possibly lost: 233 bytes in 3 blocks
==7998==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7998==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

**Edit #2:**
Fixed exception thrown in Destructor.

**Edit #3:**
Removed FileException class, using std::runtime_error instead.

**Edit #4:**
Added NULL check in deleter.

Comment: `FileDeleter::operator()` is called from a destructor, while an exception is being thrown. _Don't_ throw another exception in there. Also, what errors or leaks did valgrind show you?

Comment: One way around that is to provide an optional throwing member function and make the destructor silently fail.

Comment: You have a dangling reference problem. Change `FileException::_what` from a reference to a plain value (and if using C++11, also change the constructor to take a value instead of a reference, and `move` the argument into the member).

Comment: You can't move from a `const std::string`: your move constructor should be `File::File(std::string path)`.

Comment: Since `FileException` inherits from `runtime_error` you don't need anything in the body of the class other than `using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;` to provide the functionality you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following problems:

1. `fclose(NULL)` is not allowed ...

   - but fortunately `std::unique_ptr` doesn't call the deleter if `get() == nullptr`, so this should be ok here
2. `FileDeleter:operator()` is called from a destructor, which means *it should never throw*. In your specific case, any error returned from fclose will cause `std::terminate` to be called
3. your exception should store the string by value, not reference. That reference is to a temporary which will have been destroyed by the time you call `what()`.

   - As Vlad & Praetorian pointed out, you can remove the buggy code instead of fixing it, and just let `std::runtime_error` handle that for you. TBH, unless you're planning to add some file-specific data to the exception, or you plan to catch file exceptions separately, you don't need this class at all.

Edit: with the valgrind output provided, it looks like stack unwinding never completed. Since my initial thought about `FileDeleter::operator()` being called and throwing looks wrong, a reasonable test would be: what happens if you stick a try/catch inside the body of main?

---

General notes:

1. never throw an exception inside a destructor
2. never call something else that might throw, from a destructor

because if your destructor is invoked during exception handling/stack unwinding, the program will terminate instantly.

Comment: As for p.3, there is no need to store anything as [`runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) already does this (the right way).

Comment: `unique_ptr` will not invoke the deleter if the owned pointer is `nullptr`, so there's no need for the NULL check

Comment: Is fclose(NULL) really not valid? The man page says it sets errno with EBADF if the fp is not valid.

Comment: So how should I check/react to the return value of fclose? Because If the ctor doesn't throw, fclose gets called on a regular file and therefore returns a value...

Comment: If you're already in a destructor - even if an exception isn't in flight - what can you usefully do? Maybe log something, but throwing is unlikely to be constructive.

Comment: @user2036087 You can provide a `int close()` method to close early and return a status for users that are interested.

Comment: @Useless You are right in general though, you should check for invalid conditions within the deleter, because `shared_ptr` does call the deleter no matter what, and someone might construct a `shared_ptr` from a `unique_ptr`. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c601161ad829d118)

Comment: So I tried to apply all mentioned suggestions but Valgrind still mentions the 3 blocks mentioned above as "possibly" missing. Is this just Valgrind not being sure, or are there still leaks somewhere, that I'm not aware off as of now? Additionally, should the deleter be declared as 'noexcept' now?